# android language folder for two different language

Tags: android, multilingual

I have two languages in my app. English and urdu. I have created two folder for strings.xml.
1.values( Default for English)
2.values-ar (for urdu)

Now when I set Locale for english it is working fine in phone and tablet. But when I set locale to urdu and then in phone it is showing urdu text but in tablet it is showing english.

Please explain why this is happening.
As per my understanding application should pick string on the base of locale set.

[Here they haven't specified anything about phone and tablet](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have different layout folders for tablet or it uses same?

Comment: could you please tell us whats your tablet and phone model?

Comment: @juned I have same layout folder for tablet and phone.

Comment: @milad I using nexus 5 phone and asus memo pad

Comment: put your strings in values-fa and then test it again maybe your tablet doesn't support urdu.

Comment: @Milad . Okay thanks that I will check. another issue is that When I change orientation local also change from urdu to english in both phone and iphone. do you have any idea?

Comment: put this line in your manifest in application tag         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" that may solve the second issue. let me know if it works with -fa

Answer (score 1):

ar is for Arabic language.

Try using values-ur for urdu

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the localization with this code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar_UR");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Your resource folder (`values-ar`) is not wrong, you just need to define the code above. If `"ar_UR"` wont work, try to find the localization code in Google. The format is:

`ar` = country code (lowercase text)

`_` = separator from this two code

`UR` = language code (UPPERCASE text)